# ASP.net Rest API being redirected to login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service

I'm converting a Webforms App from using on premises LDAP Auth (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement , System.Security) to Azure AD , with SSO and AAD roles.

SSO is working, but when I try access one of my Rest API's , I get an HTTP response code 302 (Found /redirected) to/from https://login.microsoftonline.com  - obviously because of SSO.

the API's are written in the code behind file (aspx.cs) in this fashion

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<someclass> GetThings()
    {
        List<someclass> dict = new BusinessObjects().GetStuff();
        return dict;
    }
```

What is wrong here?
Do I need to add Authentication to the API's? should it be token/bearer ?

my StartupAuth.cs looks like this :

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    //custom code
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        var claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
                        //add Azure Active Directory Groups to the context. Requires "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",  in manifest file in Azure Portal
                        var groups = from c in claims
                                     where c.Type == "groups"
                                     select c;

                        foreach (var group in groups)
                        {
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, group.Value));
                        }

                        //add Azure Active Directory Roles to the context. Requires entries in "appRoles": [] in manifest file in Azure Portal
                        var roles = from r in claims
                                    where r.Type == "roles"
                                    select r;

                        foreach (var role in roles)
                        {
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, role.Value));
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    //AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => {

                    //}

                }

            }
            );

        // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It is recommended that you write a test GET method, start your project, and then log in to Microsoft. After the login is complete, access the request you just wrote. Is it normal?

Comment: Then open the privacy mode and directly access this test method to see if it will redirect. If the first method can be accessed normally, and the second redirection, then the program is all normal, you can consider to bring the beartoken parameter when accessing the interface.